# How does Vue prevent the browser sending request to server after the url in address bar is changed?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

In a traditional html page, if there is a link `<a href='www.xxx.com'>` clicked, the page will be redirected to that new page.

In the `Vue` applcation, we use `Router`. Here is the code below.

```
Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/heroes',
    },
    {
      path: '/heroes/:id',
      name: 'hero-detail',
      // props: true,
      props: parseProps,
      component: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "bundle.heroes" */ './views/hero-detail.vue'),
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      component: PageNotFound,
    },
  ],
});
```

We open the page in the browser, and it loads the main page. In this page, there is a link button, and `this.$router.push` will be invoked while the button is clicked.

After clicking the link button, the url in the browser address bar is chagned. Usually the browser will send a request to the server when the address is chagned. But the browser never sends a request to the server in `Vue`. How does `Vue` prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

On vue-router [package](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/) there a function called `guardEvent`. It looks like it prevents redirection on different situations.

```js
function guardEvent (e) {
  // don't redirect with control keys
  if (e.metaKey || e.altKey || e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey) { return }
  // don't redirect when preventDefault called
  if (e.defaultPrevented) { return }
  // don't redirect on right click
  if (e.button !== undefined && e.button !== 0) { return }
  // don't redirect if `target="_blank"`
  if (e.currentTarget && e.currentTarget.getAttribute) {
    var target = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('target');
    if (/\b_blank\b/i.test(target)) { return }
  }
  // this may be a Weex event which doesn't have this method
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, it seems that this `guardEvent ` watching some event. Do you konw what event is it watching?